# Can someone provide the URL for obtaining a Provisioning Profile?

Tags: iphone

I downloaded a new SDK version and now I get this error.

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I don't need to deploy to the device just get my project running in XCode.

Thanks in advance.
jpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to deploy, try selecting "iPhone Simulator 3.0" from the Active SDK popup, rather than "iPhone Device".

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the iPhone Developer Program Portal on the top left after you sign into developer.apple.com/iphone and then you can find it on the bottom left of the menu on that page